# I cannot receive push notification on my vritual device android

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, android-virtual-device

I received it in my vritual device before...but after I uninstall and reinstalled my app from my AVD then I didnt get any messages but in firebase console its showing completed status..plz some one help me

```js
This is Main Activity 

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ImageButton budbtn=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.buddies);
        budbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent= new Intent(MainActivity.this,BuddiesAct.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        ImageButton prim=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.primary);
        ImageButton senior=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.senior);
        ImageButton suprsen=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.supersenior);
    }
}
```

```js
Project level built gradle

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

```js
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.zion.kidskount"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'gr.pantrif:easy-android-splash-screen:0.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Is your AVD with Android O version?

Comment: no its 4.2 @EmílioFonseca

Comment: Did you get your push registration ID again after reinstalling your application?

Comment: no bro..I just downloaded jason file and configured it by adding dipendencies and google services..when i send my first message it works fine after that i tried several time it works good..this problem starts only after i uninstalled my app and re-installed it.. then i changed the icon for my app in manifest is theare any solution for this bro? @ReazMurshed

Comment: Please share some of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everytime you reinstall or clear data of your application, your `token` is generated again.

Log your token everytime `onTokenRefresh()` is called as described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client).

So, get your token and use it to send your push notification :D

Comment: thank you very much bro...thanks a lot @Emilio Fonseca